# unable to see referrer for IE version11

Tags: html, security, internet-explorer, hyperlink, referrer

I'm working on a sample project and trying to see the referrer in IE. Below is the code I tried. Any suggestions?

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>First Web Application</title>
</head>

<body>
    <span style="color: #ff0000; ">${errorMessage}</span>
    <form method="post">
        Name : <input type="text" name="name" />
        Password : <input type="password" name="password" /> 
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
<%--
    <button title="Link that opens in a new window" onclick="window.location.href='https://localhost:8082/welcome-get?token=ghgshshdg'">Next</button>
--%>
    <a title="Link that opens in a new window" onclick="window.open(this.href,'this.name');return false;" referrerpolicy="origin" href="https://localhost:8082/welcome-get?token=st566565">Next</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [official document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/178066/info-internet-explorer-does-not-send-referer-header-in-unsecured-situa) available for Referer-related issues but this issue looks a little bit different. I can also see the issue while passing the Referer from HTTPS to HTTPS. While in other browsers Referer works fine.

I made some tests with the IE 11 browser and try to narrow down the issue.

I found in your code that you are trying to open a web page in a new window and getting an empty referer. The same result I got on my side.

I suggest you if possible then remove the **OnClick** event and try to add the `target="_blank"` will help you to open the page in a new tab/window and it will also pass the referer.

Sample code:

```
<a title="Link" referrerpolicy="origin" href="https://Your_URL_here..." target="_blank">Next1</a>
```

Output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]

Comment: But the requirement is too open in new window, thats the main problem.

Comment: referrer is working when i open in same tab but not working in servienow,any idea?

Comment: @sindhu, Please see my updated answer. It can help you to pass the referer in the IE 11 while opening the new tab/window.

Comment: thanks @Deepak-MSFT , this is working in my local but  referrer is empty when i am working with the same application through service now. we were stuck there and client needs it. could you help with one please.

Comment: I try to check about ServiceNow and it looks like a third party software company. I am not aware of how you are using it. If we talk about your question then you can see that the solution can work with the IE browser. If you are having an issue with ServiceNow then I suggest you try to contact their support. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks deepak for the help